# Descargar como PDF un webform generado desde itexsharp

Tags: asp.net, pdf, itextsharp

Tengo un `webform` donde partiendo desde una imagen `.jpg`, la completo con datos de la transacción en cuestión utilizando `itextsharp` y la abro con un `windows.open`.

El problema es que al oprimir el icono de descarga, el formulario se me descarga como `.aspx` y lo estaría necesitando como `.pdf`. ¿Cómo podría llegar a lograr esto?

Comment: Deberias reformular tu pregunta. No se entiende demasiado. Publicar algo de codigo nos seria de utilidad para poder ayudarte de  la mejor manera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes de retornar el archivo en el Response especificandole el nombre de descarga y el content type:

```
string rutaArchivo= "c:/archivos/reporte.pdf";
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", // especificando que lo descargue como pdf
   string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", System.IO.Path.GetFileName( nombreArchivo)));
Response.TransmitFile(rutaArchivo); 
Response.End();
```